# Regex matching character that does not appear to be there

Tags: regex

I am trying to get some javascript cookie definitions using regex, but on one occassion something weird happens. The regex i use is `~document.cookie\s*=\s*([^\n|^\r|^}]+)~`
and when it runs over the following string

```
<!--
document.cookie = "stvisitor=noref|1|; path=/;"
// -->
```

the match is only `"stvisitor=noref` instead of the entire thing up to the new line character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
~document.cookie\s*=\s*([^\n\r}]+)~
```

Keep in mind that all characters inside a character class are seen as literals except: `^` at the begining of the class, escape sequences (like `\n`) and `-` between two characters.

In other words `|` inside a character class is not a logical OR but only the `|` character.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong. Try this:

```
/document.cookie\s*=\s*(.*)$/
```

You're using: `([^\n|^\r|^}]+)`

which is interpreted as:

```
[^\n|^\r|^}]+ match a single character not present in the list below
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\n matches a fine-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
|^ a single character in the list |^ literally
\r matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)
|^} a single character in the list |^} literally
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use pipe(|) inside the third brackets.

```
~document.cookie\s*=\s*([^\n\r}]+)~
```